# What is the proper way to reuse a ParticleSystem in Andengine?

Tags: android, andengine

It seems that creating a pool and .recyling the system when I am done with it causes an increase in velocity and other attributes on reuse. Has anyone successfully reused a particleSystem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like you are not properly detaching the ParticleSystem, so that it receives twice the updates, resulting in everything happening faster.

Comment: It seems to now display the particles at the previously used location before appearing at the new location. More details can be found [here](http://www.andengine.org/forums/post21034.html#p21034)